# unity touch hold button for android game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to add a hold for my game but doesn't work for some reason.
The game was made for PC but I ported to android to test.

update

```
    void Update( ) {
        movement = Input.GetAxisRaw( "Horizontal" );
    }
```

fixedupdate

```
    void FixedUpdate( ) {
        if ( Input.GetMouseButton( 0 ) ) {
            transform.RotateAround( Vector3.zero, Vector3.forward, movement * Time.fixedDeltaTime * move_speed );
        }
    }
```

for some reason, `transform.RotateAround` doesn't work but `transform.Rotate` works.

any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: So your if statement works for android?, but RotateAround function doesn't do anything? Are you sure its being called? Whats your "movement" variable value when you debug it?

Comment: @MilosRomanic Yes, ```transform.Rotate``` works but ```RotateAround``` doesn't.
Yes, it is being called, and the variables are:
```movement = Input.GetAxisRaw( "Horizontal" );```
```public float move_speed = 600f;```

Comment: Well if your movement is 0f then your angle by which you are rotating (movement * Time.fixedDeltaTime * move_speed will be zero), hence it wont rotate

Comment: Are you holding down both the mouse button and a horizontal key?

Comment: @MilosRomanic He is reassigning movement in Update

Comment: fixed it, had to remove the getaxisraw.
thanks.